# Load balancing in Postfix MTA

Tags: postfix, load-balancing, email-server, centos5

I have a CentOS 5.5 64 bit mail server running Postfix.  I want to do load balancing of mails sent/received to this server.

My Postfix MTA will relay mail to other two servers who will perform the SMTP service to send or receive mail messages.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Could you add the reason you want to load-balance to your question?  What resource have you run out of - CPU, RAM, IOPS, open network connections, bandwidth, inodes, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt) in TCP mode. I tried it before to load balance incoming SMTP traffic on several SMTP servers (postfix), and it worked fine. You can also allow connections coming from specific IP addresses only if applicable in your case.

Comment: ok i will try this and inform you.

Comment: Is there any other method to do this like creating multiple postfix instances and transfer of mail load to them by changes in main.cf file of postfix.